# Сессия  в php

Tags: php, сессия

Добрый день!
Из файла ses.php передаю  методом GET две переменные(сначала одну потом вторую по ссылкам) файлу ses1.php, потом хочу вывести форычем массив $_SESSION['w'] в файле
ses.php, не  получается.

//----------файл ses.php----------

```
<?php
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['w']."<br />" ;

foreach($_SESSION['w'] as $sess){
    print $sess."< br />";
}

?>

<a  href="ses1.php?w=5">Метод Get</a><br />

<a  href="ses1.php?w=6">Метод Get</a>
```

//----------- файл ses1.php------------

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['w']['']   =  $_GET['w'];

header("Location:  ses.php ");
?>
```

Comment: `$_SESSION['w'][]   =  $_GET['w'];`

Comment: выдаёт ошибку

Comment: Удивительно) по ссылочкам в ответе пройдите, там есть пример работы с сессиями)

Comment: Верх кода добавил две строчки:
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
И в строке 

$_SESSION['w'][] = $_GET['w']; убрал кавычки.Теперь выдает ошибку Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in /home/a/andr/sait/public_html/magazin/ses1.php on line 6

Comment: может в хостинге проблема

Comment: ну так глянули бы ссылки... там про хостинг и написано) пишите в саппорт, там точно помогут)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прочесть

- http://www.phpfaq.ru/sessions
- http://www.softtime.ru/bookphp/gl8_1.php

На десерт

- [https://www.google.com/search?q=php+работа+с+сессиями](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0+%D1%81+%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8)

Answer (score 0):

А в файле ses1.php после session_start(); не пробовали:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['w'])) {
    $_SESSION['w'] = array();
}
```

А потом уже

```
$_SESSION['w'][]   =  $_GET['w'];
header("Location:  ses.php ");
```